# Quick sort counting

Tags: python-3.x

Python questions again.
I want to count the number of comparison operations performed by quick sort. Because I use a recursive function, I do not think that assigning count = 0 to the beginning of the function body is inappropriate, so I made it as follows.

```
def QuickSort(lst, count = 0):
    if len(lst) > 1:
        pivot_idx = len(lst) // 2
        smaller_nums, larger_nums = [], []

        for idx, num in enumerate(lst):

            if idx != pivot_idx:
                if num < lst[pivot_idx]:
                    smaller_nums.append(num)

                else:
                    larger_nums.append(num)

        count = QuickSort(smaller_nums, count + 1)[1]
        count = QuickSort(larger_nums, count + 1)[1]
        lst[:] = smaller_nums + [lst[pivot_idx]] + larger_nums

    return lst, count
```

However, after counting, I confirmed the count which is much lower than my expectation. According to big o, the quick sort would have to show the calculation of n * log (n), but it showed a much lower count. For example, when sorting a list with 1000 random elements, we expected to see a count of 1000 * log (1000) = 6907, but actually only 1164 counts. I am wondering if I am misusing the count in the function or misunderstanding it.
Thank you.

Comment: Big O is used to give a **worst-case** time analogy, not necessarily the exact measure.

Comment: @pi4all Thanks for comment. Does my code seem correct to check counts?

Comment: Why are you not counting each iteration in the loop?

Comment: @AChampion  Because I thought that comparsion doesn not occur when idx is equal to pivot_idx. However, I realize it might be wrong.

Comment: That only accounts for one comparison out of all `n` other comparisons.

Comment: @WonKim You can only estimate the logarithmic property of growth by sorting functions of varying lengths (10, 100, 1000, 10000, 1000000, and so on). Plot the comparisons/timings/etc on a graph - prop vs size. What you get should approximate y = x log(x). Trying to calculate the exact number of comparisons is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post is mistaken on several points:

- Big-O is allows arbitrary constant factors and also ignoring the values for "small" values of n, where "small" can be arbitrarily large for any given analysis. So your computations are meaningless.
- Your counts are wrong. There's one comparison per loop iteration. You're counting something else.
- This is a strange way to code the count. Just use a global variable.

Try this. Note really you're using twice as many comparisons as this reports. The check that the loop index isn't the pivot could be eliminated with a smarter implementation.

```
c = 0

def QuickSort(lst):
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return lst
    pivot_idx = len(lst) // 2
    smaller, larger = [], []
    for idx, num in enumerate(lst):
        if idx != pivot_idx:
            global c
            c += 1
            (larger, smaller)[num < lst[pivot_idx]].append(num)
    return QuickSort(smaller) + [lst[pivot_idx]] + QuickSort(larger)

def Run(n):
    lst = [random.randint(0,1000) for r in xrange(n)]
    QuickSort(lst)
    print c

Run(1000)
```

If you're aghast at the prospect of using a global variable, then you can just wrap the sort in a class:

```
import random

class QuickSort:

    def __init__(self):
        self.comparisons = 0

    def sort(self, lst):
        if len(lst) <= 1:
            return lst
        pivot_idx = len(lst) // 2
        smaller, larger = [], []
        for idx, num in enumerate(lst):
            if idx != pivot_idx:
                self.comparisons += 1
                (larger, smaller)[num < lst[pivot_idx]].append(num)
        return self.sort(smaller) + [lst[pivot_idx]] + self.sort(larger)

def Run(n):
    lst = [random.randint(0,1000) for r in xrange(n)]
    quicksort = QuickSort()
    print quicksort.sort(lst)
    print quicksort.comparisons

Run(100)
```

Comment: "_This is a strange way to count. Just use a global variable_" Noooo... definitely don't want to use a global. It's bad practice. Even if it's alright here, it might instil a mental attitude that globals are alright, and might be used in a place where it really mustn't.

Comment: Actually I've also been trying not to use global in this practice.

Comment: @coldspeed This is clearly an experiment, not a production sort. It has _many_ problems much worse than using a global to count. Programmers need to use the right tool for the job, not adhere to rules for no reason.

Comment: @WonKim If this _were_ a production bit of software, they you'd just wrap the sort in a class to hold the counter. I've added code for that, since you seem interested.

Comment: @Gene Thanks a lot, Gene. You are a good teacher. Wish I could learn a lot from you.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer provided by Gene by adding print statements and a sort "error" range, his example was very helpful to my understanding of quicksort and an error term on the big O impact of operations performance comparison.

```
    class QuickSort:

    def __init__(self):
        self.comparisons = 0

    def sort(self, lst):
        k_err = 0 # k << n, the value the sort array can be in error 
        if len(lst) <= 1:
            return lst
        pivot_idx = len(lst) // 2
        smaller, larger = [], []
        for idx, num in enumerate(lst):
            if idx != (pivot_idx) :
                self.comparisons += 1
                try:
                  (larger, smaller)[(num - k_err) < lst[pivot_idx]].append(num)
                except:
                  (larger, smaller)[(num + k_err) < lst[pivot_idx]].append(num)
            print(pivot_idx,"larger", self.comparisons, larger)
            print(pivot_idx, "smaller", self.comparisons,  smaller, )
        return self.sort(smaller) + [lst[pivot_idx]] + self.sort(larger)

def Run(n):
    random.seed(100) 
    lst = [random.randint(0,round(100,0)) for r in range(n)]
    quicksort = QuickSort()
    print(len(lst), lst)
    print(quicksort.sort(lst))
    print(quicksort.comparisons, quicksort.comparisons/n, ((quicksort.comparisons/n)/math.log(n,10)), math.log(n,10)  )
```